# Why are miners setting the locktime in coinbase transactions?

Tags: mining-pools, coinbase-transaction, locktime

Some coinbase transactions have locktime values set. One such recent example is:

```
{
  "txid": "5166cb509a5d786db33963a269ea08ff82a1c40d37d4fb828a394b0465cd5efd",
  "hash": "075ffc5116296983aaa8286b4fdbaac101ba891a471cb835e9c532be926a7673",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 415,
  "vsize": 388,
  "weight": 1552,
  "locktime": 1026070553,
  "vin": [
    {
      "coinbase": "030ecb0a2cfabe6d6ddc5406c4378d32bde05d3b7d966ee5a6546c116e9b920d8c8564c2cff893a9dd10000000f09f909f082f4632506f6f6c2f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500fac90200",
      "txinwitness": [
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      ],
      "sequence": 0
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
    ...
```

(Its [rawtransaction here](https://mempool.space/api/tx/5166cb509a5d786db33963a269ea08ff82a1c40d37d4fb828a394b0465cd5efd/hex)).

As is apparent, the locktime is bereft of any meaning, since it is above the max block height value of 500'000'000, but with a Unix timestamp at Sun Jul 07 19:35:53 2002 UTC also set in the past.

What is its purpose? Are the mining pools attempting to communicate something?

Comment: This is the first time I hear about this, but perhaps it's used as an additional nonce that's easier to increment than the one in the txin?

Comment: Could it be a way to avoid the 101 confirmations maturity time ? Doesn't look possible but canno't figure out why they are doing that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a transaction have a locktime of 1987!](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115549/why-would-a-transaction-have-a-locktime-of-1987). P.S. I'd mark the other a duplicate of this as the other is dated later, but the other has answers that make the cause of this clearer.

Comment: The answer you linked here does not answer this question. The transaction here is not a commitment transaction and its locktime is not set to 1987.

Comment: It's possible that the locktime value was set to a specific value for a reason known only to the miner, but without more information, we can only speculate. It could be an attempt to communicate something, a form of watermarking, or simply an arbitrary choice. I recommend that you seek counsel from an F2Pool representative to respond to this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wang Chun of f2pool (@satofishi) said on Twitter](https://twitter.com/satofishi/status/1693114570728976540): “We repurpose those 4 bytes to hold the stratum session data for faster reconnect.”

He [went on to say](https://twitter.com/satofishi/status/1693537663985361038): "The coinbase locktime is set to: 500000000 + 1 << share_pdiff * 28800000 + host_id * 240000 + proc_id * 20000 + connection_id

For example, block 804186’s coinbase locktime is 0x3e9db736, which indicates the block was mined from a share which pdiff is 524288, and the share was received by pool server #13, process #10, stratum connection #3446.

The share_pdiff is also packed into stratum job_id, so that in case of connection lost, the client reconnects and sends us pre-disconnect works. Since the client may reconnect to a different pool server, which may not have the knowledge what the share’s pdiff was. Without this trick we may have to either discard the share or query a centralized database to determine that share’s pdiff. By encode pdiff into both the coinbase tx and job_id we can decode the pdiff from job_id and verify it against the pow without having to maintain a database of jobs sent."

Comment: Thank you @schmidty for your edit.