# Does everyone have a transaction that used a layer 2 protocol?

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to identify different transactions, and I was wondering if anyone knows a transaction that uses layer 2 protocols so I can further inspect it?

Comment: Instead of asking for one, why don't you create one?  Then you'd have an example where you know all the details.

Answer (score 1):

> **I was wondering if anyone knows a transaction that uses layer 2 protocols**

Assuming you may be looking for on-chain Bitcoin transactions created by L2 functions rather than looking for off-chain L2 protocols and transactions themselves.

One example is referenced in [Why would a transaction have a locktime of 1987!](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/115549/13866)

However I suspect that many on-chain transactions that are created for L2 purposes may be indistinguishable from ordinary Bitcoin transactions.