# What fields of a coinbase transaction can be empty?

Tags: transactions, mining-reward, raw-transaction, coinbase-transaction, input-script

Is it correct to say:

> As the coinbase transaction doesn't need to identify an output, there
> is no need for the input scriptSig.

**Would a block be accepted in which the coinbase transaction has an empty input scriptSig field?** Is there an example of such?

**Can any other fields be left out**, e.g. could the input TXID and VOUT be omitted (as have implied values)**?**

---

Specifically, given this example coinbase transaction (from [here](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/coinbase-transaction)):

`01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff4503ec59062f48616f4254432f53756e204368756e2059753a205a6875616e67205975616e2c2077696c6c20796f75206d61727279206d653f2f06fcc9cacc19c5f278560300ffffffff01529c6d98000000001976a914bfd3ebb5485b49a6cf1657824623ead693b5a45888ac00000000`

Would it still be accepted as (input scriptSig removed):

`01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffff01529c6d98000000001976a914bfd3ebb5485b49a6cf1657824623ead693b5a45888ac00000000`

Or even (input TXID and VOUT removed):

`0100000001ffffffff01529c6d98000000001976a914bfd3ebb5485b49a6cf1657824623ead693b5a45888ac00000000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20721/5406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would a block be accepted in which the coinbase transaction has an empty input scriptSig field? Is there an example of such?

No, for unknown reasons there is a consensus rule that the coinbase input scriptSig must be between 2 and 100 bytes in length. Its contents however does not matter; it does not need to consist of valid opcodes even.

Since BIP34 activated in 2012, there is an additional rule that the coinbase scriptSig starts with a push of the block height (in a particular format). This forces all coinbase transactions to be unique.

> Can any other fields be left out, e.g. could the input TXID and VOUT be omitted (as have implied values)?

No, because there is not even a way to signal missing fields.

Overall, a coinbase transaction is subject to these special rules:

- It has a version number and locktime like other transactions, but their values are ignored.
- It must have exactly one input:

  - Its prevout hash must be the all-zero hash (indicating it is "spending" new coins, if you will)
  - Its prevout index must be 0xFFFFFFFF, a value that cannot occur for normal UTXOs.
  - Its nSequence value must be present, but is ignored.
  - Its scriptSig must be between 2 and 100 bytes inclusive, and since BIP34 start with a push of the block height.
- It must have 1 or more outputs. These outputs are treated like all other outputs; without them, there would be no way to signal where the created/mined coins go.

Comment: re. "all-zero hash" my interpretation is that the input prevout field should be zeros `0x00000...` , not `SHA256(0x0000)`?

Comment: Also, the coinbase version and locktime can be used for arbitrary bytes? It would be interesting to find an example in the wild...

Comment: @Lee Correct. The prevout hash must be all zero bytes, not the hash of all zeroes.

Comment: > Also, the coinbase version and locktime can be used for arbitrary bytes? It would be interesting to find an example in the wild... 

@Lee check this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110474/why-are-miners-setting-the-locktime-in-coinbase-transactions/119370#119370)

Comment: It seems `nSequence` can be arbitrary too.

Comment: Yes, I said so above.

Comment: Apologies, intention was to correct/complete my previous comment.